# Masonry js modernizr animation doesn't work

Tags: animation, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to get MasonryJS to animate on resizing the window.  Masonry itself is working but not the animation.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/Vzufg/

Can anyone spot why this isn't working?  It should be doing something like this: http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/animating-modernizr.html

Many thanks for any pointers folks!

Comment: Why don't you just use Isotope which has Masonry built-in and much more and is equally easy to implement?

Comment: Because of the licensing.  Masonry is MIT licensed, which is what is required for this project.